# Quasar Framework: Method inside watcher is not recognized

Tags: cordova, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm trying to use watchers in a Quasar-Framework application and the method inside the watcher is not recognized as a method.

```
 data () {
   return {
     education: { degree:'test' },
     type: 2
   }
 },
 watch: {
   type: (newType) => {
     if (newType === 1) {
       this.removeDegree()
     }
   }
 },
 methods: {
   removeDegree () {
     this.education.degree = ''
   }
 }
```

I expect the removeDegree to be called, however, Warning & Errors are thrown which says the removeDegree is not a function.

Reference: [VueJS: Watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

**SOLUTION:**
Using the shorthand es6 syntax as suggested by @docnoe

```
watch: {
  type (newType) {
    if (newType === 1) {
      this.removeDegree()
    }
  }
},
...
```

Comment: First the `data` object is not defined correctly - it should be function that returns an object.
Next, I think the arrow function in your watcher makes the problem, so `this` is not bound to the correct  context.

Comment: @BelminBedak I'm sorry. I have corrected the data returned because it was not meant to be like that. I've checked on the suggestions by docnoe and yes you are correct, there should be no arrows anymore. I'm posting the solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Belmin Bedak already answered it in his comment: The arrow function used with the watch on "type" breaks the reference to "this". Use a normal function instead.

Fixed code:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      education: { degree: "test" },
      type: 2,
      type2: 2,
      type3: 3
    };
  },
  watch: {
    // shorthand es6 syntax
    type(newType) {
      if (newType === 1) {
        this.removeDegree();
      }
    },
    // this is also valid
    type2: function(newType) {
      if (newType === 1) {
        this.removeDegree();
      }
    },
    // or using a handler
    type3: {
      handler(newType) {
        if (newType === 1) {
          this.removeDegree();
        }
      },
      // other watch options
      immediate: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeDegree() {
      this.education.degree = "";
    }
  }
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/docnoe/pen/aVrOBr)

Comment: Shorthand es6 syntax worked 100% for me. Thank you @docnoe. You were also correct about Belmin Bedak's answer.